# Prevent Users from Manually Editing the Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I created a web app using Google Apps Script and sharing the link with editor access to other users is needed, otherwise, their input in the web app will not be recorded in the the spreadsheet connected to it.

My worry is if they manually edit the spreadsheet since they have editor access to it.

Is there a way to prevent them from editing the sheet manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Deploy the web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions) with the **Execute the app as me** option to run it under your account. You do not need to share the spreadsheet or the script with anyone.

See the [Web App Demo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153205/269219) answer for more information.

Comment: cool it's working! thanks however the Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); is no longer working. :(

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: hi i tested with our email address with same domain. it is working fine. thanks a lot!

Comment: @doubleunary This isn't the first OP's question. They already have 7 questions (not counting deleted questions)